# If $\lim\limits_n \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = 0$, then $\lim\limits_n \sqrt[n]{|a_{n+1}|} = 0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I was wondering if whenever you had a sequence of complex numbers $a_n$ such that $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ tends to $0$, then also the shifted sequence $\sqrt[n]{|a_{n+1}|}$ also tended to $0$.  In other words, whether a power series $a_0 +a_1z + \cdots $ defining an entire function induced an entire function $a_1 + a_2z + a_3z^2 + \cdots$.  This seems like it should be always be the case.  For example, if the ratio test is conclusive, then certainly you can shift indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
$$|a_{n+1}|^{1/n}=\left(|a_{n+1}|^{1/(n+1)}\right)^{(n+1)/n}.$$
Note that $\frac{n+1}{n}\gt 1$.

Thus if $|a_{n+1}|^{1/(n+1)}\lt 1$ then $|a_{n+1}|^{1/n}\le |a_{n+1}|^{1/(n+1)}$.

But from the assumption that $|a_k|^{1/k}$ has limit $0$, we can deduce that after a while $|a_{n+1}|^{1/(n+1)}\lt 1$.  The result follows.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \to 0$ **iff** ${1 \over n} \log |a_n| \to - \infty$ (convergence in the extended reals, letting $\log 0 = - \infty$).

Then
${1 \over n} \log |a_n| \to - \infty$ **iff** ${1 \over n+1} \log |a_{n+1}| \to - \infty$ **iff** ${1 \over n} \log |a_{n+1}| \to - \infty$.